# Change Adminer to PhpMyAdmin in Local WP

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, adminer

I'm learning Wordpress development, but I really prefer to use the phpmyadmin instead of adminer. How can I change it in local WP?

I really don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't have anything to do with Adminer or phpMyAdmin. WordPress uses a database to store information, and both Adminer and phpMyAdmin are tools to manage a database. You can use either Adminer or phpMyAdmin (or both simultaneously) to administrate your database, or you could do it by hand with the command line client.

So to have both phpMyAdmin and Adminer available, just [install phpMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html). If you don't want Adminer, you can remove it. As long as you don't also remove your database, your WordPress will be unaffected.

Of course, it's always a good idea to make a backup and dump your database to an SQL file before making any system changes.